# Got a new hard drive, old one is dying - can Windows tell me when I'm writing or reading from the old one with symlinks?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, backup, symbolic-link

Bear with me, as this is a little convoluted. I have a 1 tb hard drive that I've been using for over 6 years with most of my, let's just say, 'entertainment' of various sorts being written to and read from it. Now I'm fairly sure I can adjust the programs (Kodi, download clients, MPC, etc.) that read from, and write to it, to point to the new location on my new hard drive - but I may miss a few since there are quite a few random programs that I rarely use that utilize the old location.

Now since my old hard drive is currently dying, I wanted to move everything over en masse and create symlinks (Or the Windows 8.1 equivalent) to point to the new location. This helps me short term, and helps me long term if I can remember every program that points to my old hard drive - but I may not be able to, and I'd hate to load up a program months from now when I remove my old drive and have to adjust everything to point to the new location all over again.

So I'm wondering, is the below possible? If not, what can I do to help me long term without getting (Hopefully non-silent) errors when I eventually take out my old drive.

**What I want to do**

Create symlinks on the old partition's letter to point to the new location for every individual root folder I move, and have Windows or some program notify me when the symlink is being used to access the new location (So I can remedy it per-program)

Comment: Why not simply clone the old drive to the new drive, and throw the old drive away ?   If the new drive is bigger you can resize it as well.  A lot easier and more robust then messing with symlinks.

Comment: Clonezilla,acronis, or etc clone the whole drive and be done with it, like davidgo suggests.

Comment: @davidgo the new drive is a lot bigger, and I forgot to mention that I'm moving files and folders from several drives to the new one. While I will be throwing away the dying one, I'll be keeping the other one I'm moving (Some) files frmo.